# Nodal analysis with current dependent voltage source

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

V2= 4Ix + V1 (1)

V1 Node

V1/6 + V1-V3/12 + V2/2 + V2-V3/3 =0 (2)

V3 Node

1 + V2-V3/3 + V1-V3/12 = 0 (3)

I can get this three equation by text book, but I can't understand equation (1). Can anyone explain how can I get equation (1)?

Comment: Equation 1 is wrong. You're adding current to voltage, which is mathematically (and physically) impossible.

Comment: Ix is v2/2 by oms'law so 4Ix is  4(v2/2) I think..

Comment: @JonathanS. in this situation the "4" is in ohms so, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Can anyone explain how can I get equation (1)?*

\$V_2 = 4\cdot I_x + V_1\$ is correct in that the voltage at the node marked \$V_2\$ is the series addition of the voltage at node \$V_1\$ plus the dependent voltage source output given by \$4\cdot I_x\$

Voltage \$V_2\$ also equals \$I_x \times 2\text{ }\Omega\$